# isolating an angular service for each controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use Angular services to put my common codes that i use in everywhere. it works but right now i found out something strange! Variables in service shared between controllers and if i have two controllers in a page, if one controller changes a variable, it affects other controller.

But i don't want it! i need a system like services but with an isolated environment for each controller. is there any way?

**UPDATE:**

```
app.service("myService",function(){
   this.variable = 1;
});

app.controller("loginCtrl",function($scope,myService){
    console.log(myService.variable); //prints 1
    myService.variable++;
});

app.controller("signupCtrl",function($scope,myService){
    console.log(myService.variable); //prints 2
});
```

I need each controller use a new myService(isolated)

Comment: @Moncef Hassein-bey: i updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All services in AngularJS are singletons.  As a result, any injected singleton can be affected by another controller.  That said, you can also deliberately create a new instance of an injected service which will guarantee isolated scope provided that you don't inject shared services into your instanced service.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="signupCtrl">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("loginCtrl", ['$scope', 'sharedService', function($scope, sharedService){
    var myService = sharedService.getInstance();
    console.log(myService.variable); //prints 1
    myService.variable++;
}]);

app.controller("signupCtrl", ['$scope', 'sharedService', function($scope, sharedService){
    var myService = sharedService.getInstance();
    console.log(myService.variable); //prints 1
}]);

app.factory('sharedService', [function () {
    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            return new instance();
        }
    }

    function instance () {
        this.variable = 1;
    }
}]);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qegr5jyc/)

Comment: thanks you my friend. it works, but right now i edited my code, i have to use $timeout service in my service like this: app.service("sharedSystem", [function ($timeout) {...   but my code inside that service doesn't know about $timeout. in a simple service, it works.

Comment: Inject it with the array syntax to ensure it's injection safe: `app.service("sharedSystem", ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {}]);`